# Oracle Database Setup.exe file not executing after extracting into folder on windows

Tags: oracle, data-warehouse, oracle19c

I am trying to install oracle 19c DB but after extraction the setup.exe file isn't executing. I have tried it with admin privileges, still doesn't work.

Comment: In my case I need to move the extracted folder outside of windows downloads folder and then it started working

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, and after playing a bit with things I figured out that this is all about the folder name in which setup.exe is in.

*## The solution:*


**Make sure there are no white-spaces in your folder name** (or possible in the path in general, haven't checked that, but it makes sense).
Once you renamed the folder to a white-space-less name, you can just run setup.exe directly from that folder.

Answer (score 4):

I have found the solution:

1- After extraction, shorten the name to db_home (just take off the first few characters in the name).

2- Move or copy the db_home directory to the root of your HD (I have mine on an external 6 TB HD & I just moved the folder to its root).

You will see a cmd window pop up and then the red window with the Oracle symbol in it.

Be patient, as the installation window will also pop up, and be patient again because my computer then after about a minute poped up with another window asking me if I wanted to allow a service to start (which you will have to allow).

After several more seconds the installation window finally showed the install options in it.

Then I could install it.

Do NOT skip step #2, as that is how I was finally able to get it to install.

This also worked with 19c.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that the controlling factor was that your "original"  "oracle home" had a space somewhere in the directory name.

Answer (score 1):

I tried installing Oracle Database 19c for the Windows x64 version, you have to rename the folder containing no whitespaces and put it in the root folder (C:/ or D:/) drive.
Try starting the setup again, a command prompt will open and after some mins, the setup will start.

Note: Keep your windows updated.

Answer (score 0):

move the folder containing setup file in your root folder it can be C:\ drive or D:.
folder name should not contain any white space and run the setup file as administrator.

Answer (score -1):

This happen frequently when some Windows packages are missing. Try to update your OS and launch the setup file again.